# Не работает команда mail

Tags: email, php

Не работает команда `mail()` на собственном сервере под windows. Установлен xampp

Comment: Как вы определили, что не работает?

Comment: Посмотрите [в этой статье](http://i--gu.ru/urok-1) раздел "Делаем почтовую заглушку sendmail для XAMPP"

Comment: @cas-live, Я понимаю, так может она стоит?

Comment: Тогда явно какие-то настройки sendmail хромают, [почитайте тут](http://webi.ru/webi_articles/sendmail_ini.html).

Comment: Нужно попробовать отправить email на разные хостинги (gmail, yandex, mail, rambler, etc) для того чтобы утверждать что mail() не работает. Возможно ваше письмо не содержит нужных хедеров или ваш IP каким-то образом попал в список "плохих" IP.

Comment: Или вообще все письма приходят но в папку "Спам". Загляните туда.

Comment: сделайте error_handler и посмотрите реальную ошибку.

    set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
    set_exception_handler('my_exception_handler');

    function my_exception_handler($e) {
        exit('Huston! We have a problem: '.$e);
    }

    function my_error_handler($no,$str,$file,$line) {
        $e = new ErrorException($str,$no,0,$file,$line);
        my_exception_handler($e);     /* Do not throw, simply call        error handler with exception object */
    }

Comment: Нечего не выдает

Comment: значит mail() отрабатывает, теперь вам на форум админов